# HTML form doesn't submit after successful AJAX validation

Tags: forms, jquery

I have a simple HTML form that uses uses ajax in part of the validtion. the ajax works correctly and display errors correctly, but if all validation passes, the form doesn't submit. Basically, nothing happens. Nothing happens in Firebug, nothing happens on the page itself, etc. This is the Javascript that's called to validate the form:

```
var pass_form = $('#pass_form');
pass_form.submit( valid_pass_sett );

function valid_pass_sett() {
    $('.caption_error').remove();
    $('input').removeClass('error');
    pass_old = $('input[name=pass_old]').val();
    pass_new = $('input[name=pass_new]').val();
    pass_confirm_new = $('input[name=pass_confirm_new]').val();

    if (pass_old === "") {
        //display error on form - snipped
        return false;
    } else if (pass_new === "") {
        //display error on form - snipped
        return false;
    } else if (pass_new != pass_confirm_new) {
        //display error on form - snipped
        return false;
    } else if (pass_new.length < 8) {
        //display error on form - snipped
        return false;
    } else {

        $.post("http://www.example.com/ajax/validate.php",{ // async validation
            type: 'valid_old_change_pass', 
            pass_old: pass_old,
            pass_new: pass_new
        }, valid_pass_combo_callback);

    }
    return false;  // cancel form submission
}

function valid_pass_combo_callback( data ) {
    if (data == 'valid') {
        //only if the form is valid!
        pass_form[0].unbind('submit').submit();
        //pass_form[0].submit();
    } else if (data == "invalid_old") {
        //display error on form - snipped
    }
    else if (data == "invalid_new") {
        //display error on form - snipped
    }
    else {
        //display error on form - snipped
    }
}
```

and here's the basic HTML code for the form:

```
<form id="pass_form" class="standard" method="post" action="http://www.example.com/preferences" onsubmit="return valid_pass_sett()">
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label for="pass_old">Old password:</label>

            <input type="password" id="pass_old" name="pass_old" />
        </div>
                <div>
            <label for="pass_new">New password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="pass_new" name="pass_new" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pass_confirm_new">Confirm new password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="pass_confirm_new" name="pass_confirm_new" />
        </div>
                <div>
            <label></label>
            <input type="submit" id="pass_submit" name="pass_submit" value="Change password"/>

            <input type="reset" id="pass_reset" name="pass_reset" value="Cancel"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The script makes it all the way to the `pass_form[0].unbind('submit').submit();` line, but then the form doesn't submit. Any help here?

Comment: You do `return false;  // cancel form submission` and you wonder why the form isn't submitted?

Comment: You're posting to the same domain that's serving the page, right?

Comment: Have you used firebug to see if the submission takes place?  With firebug, you can view ajax calls and even view the data you submitted.  Possibly, it was encoded wrong or something?

Comment: @PeeHaa, it's an AJAX request, the form shouldn't be submitted. Have you checked the console for errors or checked that it reaches the AJAX request stage?

Comment: @PeeHaa - someone had mentioned to me in another thread that the `return false` statement there cancelled form submission to make sure the ajax call went through; that's why the form is only submitted in the callback function. If I *remove* `return false` the form submits before the ajax call is complete, which isn't correct.

Comment: @waitinforatrain: I think the AJAX call is just for validation and if the form is valid the form should just be submitted.

Comment: @pythonscript Then the error is in the call back function??

Comment: @jen - I don't know where the error is; I'm assuming it's somewhere in the callback function, but that's why I posted for help. 

@Kyle - on submit, firebug simply doesn't do anything. I have it set to break on next, but nothing happened. Using an alert statement, I know that the code *is* getting to the `data=='valid'` statement, however. Something about the `pass_form[0].unbind('submit').submit();` is failing, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to forgo binding this function to submit, and instead bound to an onclick event for a button on the form (which I'm using in place of a submit button) and that solved the problem. Validation is called when the button is clicked, and if client-side validation passes, then the form is submitted to the server for validation there.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line in your callback method `valid_pass_combo_callback`

```
//Replace this line

   pass_form[0].unbind('submit').submit();

//By this

   pass_form.unbind('submit').submit();
```

Comment: Still nothing. The form doesn't submit.

Comment: What is the value of `data` in the callback? Can you alert that and see?

Comment: If it is going inside the `data == 'valid'` condition then can you try `pass_form.unbind('submit')[0].submit();`?

Comment: The value of data is `valid` and the `data == 'valid'` condition is working. Just the submit. `pass_form.unbind('submit')[0].submit();` doesn't work either. No submit.

Comment: I added a new edit to my initial answer, because I solved the problem a different way. The above solutions didn't work, so I used an onlick event instead of a submit event. See my last edit to my question for the full details.